# Spring security check effective date and expire date before login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to check if user has passed the **effective date** and **is not expired** before login. How should I do it? I have both custom `authenticationsuccesshandler` and `authenticationfailurehandler`.

```
<form-login login-page="/login" 
  authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
  authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
  authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandlerWithoutReferer1"/>
```

spring-security.xml

```
  <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                           users-by-username-query="select USER_ID,USER_PWD,USER_STATUS from USER where USER_ID=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from authorities where username =?  " />
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) interface.

```
@Service("customUserService")
public class CustomUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // find out all necessary information about the user
        // for example, use JdbcTemplate to query from your data source
        // note especially the boolean accountNonExpired below
        return new User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }
}
```

You can't use the `jdbc-user-service` tag. Instead:

```xml
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserService">
    <!-- password encoder etc -->
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: docs tell you not to do the authentication in `userDetailsService`, though it seems easier proper way is to use `customAuthenticationProvider` for custom authentication processing

Comment: @user1289300 Checking if account is expired is not doing authentication. A custom authentication provider is more (harder) work.

Comment: @holmis83 you are right. As I am a newbie to spring security. BTW, will `AuthenticationFailureHandler` crash with `UserDetailsService`?

Comment: you have to mean something else because `AuthenticationFailureHandler` has no acces to your `UserDetailsService` it only handles thrown `AuthenticationException` implemantations, and whatever they are should be based on your authentication process, therfore depending on the type of implementation of `AuthenticationException` you can configure desired action after user authentication failed

Comment: @holmis83 if you look at `UserDetails` interface you will see that authentication will fail, if account is expired, so it is part of the process of authentication I would say

Answer (score 0):

If you need some special case authentication according to docs you have to implement AuthenticationProvider

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-userdetailsservice

then add it to your `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` if you are using javaconfig. 
If using metadata I think you need to do something like this:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Can I just add `<authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>` to my xml? (check edited)

Comment: I dont really remember whats the best way o add it in metadata but the point is you have to implement custom authentication provider and supply it as your preffered authentication provider

Answer (score -1):

Create a Custom UserDetailsService implementation

Example:

```
@Service("customUserService")
public class UserServiceImpl   implements UserDetailsService{

  /**
   * Used by spring security 
   */
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

      try{
        //Do all your check 
        //create object of User and return, password can be anything
        return new User(username, password, authorities);
      }catch(NubeException e){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user_not_found");
      }
    }

}
```

Then tell spring to use your class to authenticate:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider  user-service-ref="customUserService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: So I no longer able to use my dataSource? (Check edited)

Comment: It is hack rather than proper way of doing it, documentation mentions not to do it this way, and let the detailsService remain purely DAO

Comment: Password must not be null!